# Getting how many times the most repetitive element repeats in a list

Tags: python, list

I have to store in a variable how many times the most repetitive element repeats in a list. But I should not use any list comprehension, or dictionary or counting by dictionaries. The farthest  I am able to use is list methods.

```
the_max_occurrence = max([my_list.count(x) for x in range(1,11)])
```

For example, something like this giving the same value.

Comment: do you have to get the element which has high occurrence isn't it

Comment: Wait, so you don't want to use the `.count()` method?

Comment: What is the "etc" in your question? Why not specify what *can* be used?

Comment: Is your list sorted? What is the time complexity of the answer you're looking for?

Comment: is my_list.count() allowed?

Comment: I am allowed to use count() method. But not to use list comprehension, dictionaries. Sorry I couldn't make myself clear

Comment: `max(my_list.count(value) for value in set(my_list))`

Comment: @erenrock00, check my one, it doesnt ouse any built in method of list

Comment: @rcvaram thanks so much. Seems like it's the only one I am allowed to use.

Comment: Please make it answer if it solves

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, given that my_list.count() is allowed, as you clarified in comments:

```
l=[]
for i in set(my_list):
    l.append((i, my_list.count(i)))

the_max_occurrence=max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
```

If you don't want to use any new list at all, you could do the following:

```
the_max_occurrence=0

for i in set(my_list):
    the_max_occurrence=max(the_max_occurrence, my_list.count(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement,

- We take counts for each element
- Counts are saved into a count list
- We find Maximum of the count list
- We find the index of the maximum of the counts
- we retrieve the element which is the same index of  list A

```
counts =[]

listA = [2,4,5,3,5,5,5,4,4,5,5,4,2]

for i in range(len(listA)):
  counts.append(1)
  for j in range(i+1,len(listA)-1):
     if listA[i] == listA[j]:
        counts[i] = counts[i]+1
print(counts) # [1, 4, 6, 1, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]

max = 0
for k in counts:
  if k>max:
    max = k
print(max) #6

for i in range(len(counts)):
    if counts[i] == max:
       index = i
       break
print(index) #2

high_occurace_element = listA[index]
print(high_occurace_element)  #5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list based on the number of occurrences of each element, then get the count of occurrences of the first element.

```py
lst = []
lst = sorted(lst, key=lst.count, reverse=True)
print(lst.count(lst[0]))
```

Or, as Peter's comment suggested, a simple way would be

```
max(my_list.count(value) for value in set(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use list,dict etc. Then you are writing the child's code. The best I came up with which uses basic things.

```
lst = [1, 4, 56, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
maxcount = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    mycount = 0
    for j in lst[i:]:
        if lst[i] == j:
            mycount += 1
    if mycount > maxcount:
        maxcount = mycount
print(maxcount)
```

You better not use python if you want to write this kind of code

Comment: That was not my choice. My instructor at university teaches Python from scratch. And I should edit my code as far as what he has taught. He has not taught these yet so does not want us to use these. Nevertheless, you're totally right. This is not kind of code I would like to  write. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found. (Can only sort numbers)
Does this meet your requirements?

```
def most_frequency(List):
     work_list = [int(x) for x in List]
     work_list.sort()
     counter = 0
     num = List[0] 
       
     for i in work_list: 
         curr_frequency = work_list.count(i) 
         if(curr_frequency> counter): 
             counter = curr_frequency 
             num = i 
   
     return str(num) + "," + str(curr_frequency)
```